# How can I show multiple data containing picture and text data with JQUERY/AJAX, which are sent as object or array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

I can't find a solution how to handle an object or an array sent from a server and containing binary picture and text data with JQUERY/AJAX

Ok, here is the server side:

```
const url= require('url'),
      express = require('express'),
      fs = require ('fs'),
      app = express();
// Create a server

app.listen(8080, function (){
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});

app.use (express.static (__dirname +'/public')); // provide public data,here: jQuery


app.get ("/", function (req, res){
    res.sendFile (__dirname +"/ClientServerExchange (2.5).html");
    console.log (__dirname +req.url);
});

app.get ("/image", function (req, res) {
    message = req.query.message;
    console.log (message);
    fs.readFile (message,  
    (err, myImg) => {
        var myData = {myImage: myImg, myText: "this a nice pic"};
//      var myData = [myImg, "this a nice pic"]; // if to be sent as array ...
        return res.send (myData);
    });

})
```

The client side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" >
        <title>Client-Server Exchange</title>
        <script src="JS/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
        <style>

        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            $(document).ready (function (){

                const message = encodeURI("../Workbench/Pics/myPic.jpg");

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/image?message=" +message,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    xhr: function(){// Seems like the only way to get access to the xhr object
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.ResponseType = 'blob';
                        return xhr;
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log ("Request sent");
                        var blobData = new Blob ([data.myImage]);
                        src = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
                        $("img").attr ("src", src); 
                        $("#addComment").text (data.myText);
                    },
                    timeout: 10000
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>show a picture from my little server </p>
        <img src ="">
        <p id="addComment"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The request is sent and I assume the response from the server contains all data. I can see it from the messages in both consoles. But no picture is shown, only a small symbol instead, which looks like a broken picture. The requested text appears after this symbol. There is no error message on client and server side.

The  only way to receive picture data is as shown in the xhr structure inside the `$.ajax` function. I found the solution here at the stackoverflow platform. Client script  works well, if I send picture data only (of course with slight modifications of the client and server script, but this is not the question here).

How can I program the client script, that it receives such an object and shall treat the `myImage`-part as a blob and the `myText`-part as a text?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why don't you send just the link of image?

Comment: That means to copy the image (or lot of images or folders with lot of images) into a public folder, in consequence to waste space at the server, PC, laptop or whatever, doesn't it? Ok, I can move the all images and folders into the public folder or copy selections and/or move them around etc., but I don't want to do that. For this reason I want to access them only on server side with the fs-module.I think it's more safe.

Comment: about the space i can tell you that you have to waste that space and save the image some where, in database or in a folder that doesn't make any difference how ever if you save them in a folder you can easily manage them. but about safety if safety is important and you don't want others see that you can change the permission of folder and make dynamic links for them for example like this. ```router.get('/download/:formNumber', function (req, res) {
    var file = __dirname + '/public/forms/' + req.params.formNumber + '.pdf';
    res.sendFile(file);
});
``` and check the auth

Comment: Hi Babak, 
thanks for the tip of using ```express.Router ()``` at server side. The client sends now 2 requests - one for the image and one for the title/comment. And no, it's not necessary to waste space by copying images to a public folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following to Babak's tip of using `express.Router()` I modified the program in my request a little bit.

Add to server program

```
const router = express.Router ();

app.use ("/image", router);
```

Replace there `app.get ("/image", function (req, res) { ...});` with

```
router.get ("/", function (req, res) {
    message = req.query.message;
    console.log (message);
    fs.readFile (message,  
    (err, myImage) => {
        return res.send (myImage);
    }); 
});
```

and add

```
router.get ("/Title", function (req, res) {
    res.send ("This is a nice pic!");
})
```

On client side replace `$.ajax({ ... });` with

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/image?message=" +message,
                    xhr: function(){// Seems like the only way to get access to the xhr object
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                        return xhr;
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log ("Request sent");
//                      var blobData = new Blob([data]); // not necessary
//                      var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                        src = URL.createObjectURL(data); // could be blobData, if defined, but works also without this.
                        $("img").attr ("src", src);                 
                    }
                });
```

and add below this inside `$(document).ready (function (){ ... })`

```
                $.get ("/image/Title", function (data) {
                    $("#addComment").text (data);
                })
```

Obviously it is not possible to send binary data inside an object or array (I'm not sure, because I think to have read this, but I don't know where ...). Anyway, the solution above works.